# EXTJS how to access global variables in store

Tags: extjs

I'm quite new to Extjs, I'm needing to pass some data to my stores, I mean, I need to fetch some URL from a singleton configuration file, but reading in the Official documentation I am not able to find a `require` method in the store. So, I wonder how to tell my store to fetch that URL from a configuration file?

Comment: Configuration file is present in server side or your extjs project folder ?

Comment: @Tejas, it should be in the Extjs project folder... I did a tweak on this: I'm loading an API resource which loads a simple json file with the info I need. Then I put them into the localStorage and it works for me.

Comment: Can you load that resource file on beforeLoad event of store, so that you will get required data and will set parameters for store to load.I am thinking this as straight forward approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which version of Extjs you are using. The answer is based on Extjs6 which I am using. We add the singleton (mostly common configs) files in the application(Application.js) level so that the file will be available across the entire app.

For example, 
singleton file is 'Some.Globals.configs'

//Application.js

```
Ext.define('Some.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    requires: [
        'Some.Globals.configs'
    ]
});
```

Then anywhere in the application, you can access directly as mentioned below.

Some.Globals.configs.respectiveConfig

Comment: I'm using Extjs 6.0.2, but your answer does not respond my question. Note that `requires` is not a property for stores or controllers. So what I'm doing is to load these requirements in a view that loads first than the store or the controller.

Answer (score -1):

If you are extending Ext.data.Store you should be able to use `requires` property

eg.

```
Ext.define('My.awesome.Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'My.global.Config'
    ]
    ...
});
```